# Split characters with numeric and character ranges

Tags: r, sequence, gsub

I am trying to convert a data frame of characters that sometimes contain numeric or character ranges at the end of the string. If a range is specified, I need each value of the range (A:Z|0:9) to be separated into its own row with the preceding characters pasted beforehand.

```
test.data <- data.frame("zone" = c('X','X','Y','Y'),"postal"=c('A1V','A2B-D', 'B1V 1A1','B2V 1B6-9'),stringsAsFactors = F)

> test.data
zone postal
X    A1V
X    A2B-D
Y    B1V 1A1
Y    B2V 1B6-7
```

So far I've only been able to isolate the ranges into separate elements.

```
strsplit( gsub("([[:alnum:]]-[[:alnum:]])","~\\1",test.data$postal), "~" )
```

Ideally I am looking for something like this (note the B:D and 6:9 ranges):

```
> desired.output
zone postal
X    A1V
X    A2B
X    A2C
X    A2D
Y    B1V 1A1
Y    B2V 1B6
Y    B2V 1B7
Y    B2V 1B8
Y    B2V 1B9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

range2sequence <- function(start, end) {
  s <- strtoi(start)
  e <- strtoi(end)

  # if s and e are integers
  if (!is.na(s) && !is.na(e)) {
    sequence <- as.character(seq(s, e))
    return(sequence)
  }

  s <- as.character(start)
  e <- as.character(end)
  # if s and e are letters A-Z
  if (s %in% LETTERS && e %in% LETTERS) {
    s_pos <- which(LETTERS == s)
    e_pos <- which(LETTERS == e)
    if (s_pos > e_pos)
      stop("start must be lower or equal than end.")
    return(LETTERS[s_pos:e_pos])
  }

  stop("start and end do not seem to define a valid range: ",
       start,
       " and ",
       end,
       ".")

}

expand_range <- Vectorize(function(str) {
  sub_strs <- str_match(str, "([^-]+)([^-])-([^-])")
  if (is.na(sub_strs[1]))
    return(str)
  else {
    prefix <- sub_strs[2]
    start <- sub_strs[3]
    end <- sub_strs[4]
    return(str_c(prefix, range2sequence(start, end)))
  }
})

test.data <-
  data.frame(
    "zone" = c('X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'),
    "postal" = c('A1V', 'A2B-D', 'B1V 1A1', 'B2V 1B6-9'),
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )

test.data %>%
  transform(postal = expand_range(postal)) %>%
  unnest -> desired.output

desired.output
#>   zone  postal
#> 1    X     A1V
#> 2    X     A2B
#> 3    X     A2C
#> 4    X     A2D
#> 5    Y B1V 1A1
#> 6    Y B2V 1B6
#> 7    Y B2V 1B7
#> 8    Y B2V 1B8
#> 9    Y B2V 1B9
```

Comment: @stackin: let me know if there is anything you do not understand about the code.

Comment: Fantastic code, learnt a few new functions from this as well. Could I get more details on the usage of `Vectorize` in `expand_range`? I'm guessing it is meant to convert the expanded range values so that `transform` works correctly.

Comment: @stackin: `expand_range` is a function that expects one argument, a single string (a character vector of one element only). `vectorize` makes `expand_range` work as well on a vector of several strings, i.e. it *vectorizes* this function over a character vector. So, you're right, when we get to the point of using it with `transform`, we can easily apply `expand_range` on the `postal` column (a character vector).